# Cannot enter a star sign in a WebEdit in UFT

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

UFT is failing to do a very simple task. I am trying to fill a search field that allows for star-signs as jokers in the search expression.

```
WebEdit(xyz).Set "Test*"
```

But the result is that it only puts "Test" in the field. The field is an ordinary input field in html. 
I also to catch the case where I have a star in the end using

```
WebEdit(xyz).Set "Test" & Chr(42)
```

With the same result. Using an escape "\" does not seem to work either.
Can anyone help me with this? I am using UFT 14.53

Comment: Please add some more details, what browser are you using. Does this happen on all edit fields? I tried it and it works on reddit's username field.

Comment: I work in IE11. Strange enough it does not happen always. I have other search forms where I can enter "*" signs. In some it fails at times, but I have a recovery function using SendKeys. But in this one it is consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer thanks to a colleague. Strange enough it works with SendKeys when I add a ({TAB}) or ({RETURN}).